# Can a GPU be the host of a OpenCL program?

Tags: opencl

*Little disclaimer: This is more the kind of theoretical / academic question than an actual problem I've got.*

The usual way of setting up a parallel program in *OpenCL* is to write a C/C++ program, which sets up the devices (GPU and/or other CPUs), kernel and data buffers for executing the kernel on the device.
This program gets launched from the host, which used to be a CPU.

Would it be possible to write a OpenCL program where the host is a GPU and the devices other GPUs and/or CPUs?

What would be the prerequisites for such a scenario?
Do one need a special GPU or would it be possible to use any OpenCL-capable GPU?

Comment: In a word, no that is not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a complete host or just a kernel launcher?

Up coming CUDA (v 5.0) introduces a feature to launch a kernel inside a kernel. Therefore, a device can be used for launching a kernel on itself. May be this feature will be supported by OpenCL too in near future.